# Additional Icon in App Name/Lable

Tags: iphone, ios, emoji, springboard

How can I add an additional icon to the Name/Lable of app, just the like snapshot of my test device Home screen (see highlighted Water app, in the attached screenshot). You can see that there is a small icon at the end of App Name/Label.

[image: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9836/screenshot2012032718452.png]

PS: I'm not sure, if its part of the Application icon, or there is some way to add an additional icon to App Name/Label.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Emoji to me. Didn't realize you can add it to the bundle display name... time to test this!

Comment: I can not find this app in the app store.  There is a water app, but it does not have that character.

Comment: @nycynik: Hmmm... Might be some issue of app store location, in my store it is avilable with icon. and I also have test it and it works :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an Emoji character. See [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) on Wikipedia and [iOS: Understanding emoji](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4976) for more information about these. They are special unicode characters that are very popular in countries like Japan. iOS has support for these throughout the OS, and you can see these characters on the Wikipedia page by visiting it with Safari.

You can put these characters into the "Bundle display name" (`CFBundleDisplayName`) of your Info.plist (or InfoPlist.strings) and they will appear correctly on the home screen of the device:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if this is officially allowed by Apple.

Comment: This is the link to the app which I download from app store, after install Lable/Name changes to [Water<emoji-icon>]. So I think apple officially allows this. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/water-your-body/id337998484?mt=8

Comment: To enter Emoji characters on OS X Mavericks simply hold Command-Control-Space whenever you are in a text field and an Emoji panel will appear.

Comment: I decided to try this in my app. I will return and say, whether the app passed Apple's validation

Comment: Yes, my app did pass the validation process.