# Is application name's font customizable in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way we can customize the iphone application name's font..

I downloaded a app from app store and it had a **telephone image** in the name ...

**Application name:** simple phone launcher

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-launcher-for-ipad-launch/id467950393?mt=8

Adding image:
[image]

Comment: You mean like the font on the springboard?  Also ***never*** make us download something to see what you mean.  Can you provide an image?

Comment: Sure it wasn't just the Unicode character for a telephone? Like this? ☎

Comment: Sure...I downloaded app and there is no customization in app name's font.It's has name "S.Launcher" with regular app font...

Comment: i am newbee to this group and not allowed to add images till i reach certain reputation, i will add the image once i reach that reputation

Comment: Hi ckhan what is the unicode u used to get that telephone icon ...

Comment: I hope this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891204/additional-icon-in-app-name-lable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change font of your application name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this question is no, there is no supported way to change the Springboard font for a particular application.

Even jailbroken phones which are running [Springboard equivalents appear only to have the ability to change the font for the whole Springboard](http://www.hackthatphone.com/2x/themes_with_winterboard_section15.html) (ie, for all apps), not just a particular app.

Comments above seem to indicate that the app you suggest doesn't have a customized font or graphic. But I think you may have seen a name that included the Unicode telphone character: ☎

Comment: If the phone icon on the screenshot is a unicode, how can i get this for a app. Can u please help me .. what is the unicode for red phone icon and where should i add the unicode, is it for the bundle identifier?

Comment: Copy and paste that icon you see above, and on iOS, it will show as the image you require. The Springboard name is taken from the Bundle display name in the Info.plist file.