# How to set small image symbol in application's name under Application icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

[image: I had install the ipad application as shown in image. And there's raise a question, that how to set special sybolic application name with image ? as shown in image. It will be good to know how to make it.]

I had install the ipad application as shown in image. And there's raise a question, that how to set special sybolic application name with image ? as shown in image. It will be good to know how to make it. 
Thanks,
K.D

Comment: Exactly same as @NitinGohel suggest...

Comment: My question is not for 57*57 or 114*114 app icon, but see Left and right side of Application name with "Franky", two small hearts images.

Comment: @NitinGohel application name is put by apple from what we specify in iTunes connect, and not with the application icon itself. Even if the app icon is photoshopped to contain this kind of an image, the square where the icon appears will show that photoshopped image.

Comment: Try this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891204/additional-icon-in-app-name-lable

Comment: check Vishwa's link its usefull i just post soon how to do like your requirement

Comment: check my answer mate hope its help's you :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i just study it and got the Solution at your Info.plist file --> BundulDisplayName-->DoubleClickOn Right-side at as bellow Image:-

[image]

Now just Clear `${PRODUCT_NAME}` And select Edit at upside Tool bar like bellow image:-

[image]

then now you can see the window like:-

[image]

Now `Drag` `symbol` from characters windows to `BundulDisplayName` when you put this special Symbol then put name of display you want of app then again drag second time same process after name put second symbol.

that's it now save and run your Project your icon look like:-

[image]

hope you getting you want :)

Comment: +1 for including snaps

Comment: +1 for cool idea in summer :)

Comment: wow, this is pretty nice. i will use that in my "Sunrise" app. thank you. +1 for that.